# com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Failed retrying datastore 200 times

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I was doing a stress test of running an endpoint multiple times in a short period of time. The endpoint updates the same entity in a transaction. Eventually, I got this error:

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Failed retrying datastore 200 times
```

I tried it with both `transact()` and `transactNew()` in objectify and got this error. The objectify comments specifically say that `transactNew()` retries the transaction `Integer.MAX_VALUE` times so I don't understand why I got this error at only 200 retries.

Does anyone know if this error is an objectify error or a Datastore error?

Is there a Datastore transactional limit of 200? Or is something else going on like App Engine not auto-scaling right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit in Objectify is [200](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/search?q=DEFAULT_TRY_LIMIT)

Comment: The method description for `transactNew` says `Executes work in a new transaction.  Note that this is equivalent to {@code transactNew(Integer.MAX_VALUE, work);}` - but I guess it is 200 and not int.max